# MongoDB BSON Date - formatting options in PHP toDateTime() method

Tags: php, mongodb, datetime

The documentation from the official PHP site is sorely lacking:
http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-bson-utcdatetime.todatetime.php

The examples given have parameters for formatting as 'r' and 'U.u'. These give outputs:

```
string(31) "Fri, 07 Oct 2016 10:40:01 +0000"
string(17) "1475836828.000000"
```

I can't seem to find any documentation for these. My question is, what parameter do I need to specify to get the datetime as a string in the following format:

```
"D-m-y H:i:s"
```

Comment: The examples on the manual page you link to clearly show that a [`\DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) object is returned by this function. The documentation you seek is on the manual page for `\DateTime::format()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest I managed to get was to use the argument DATE_ATOM in the format method, and then take the substring between 0 and 19 to produce string datetimes in the following format:

```
"2016-10-07T10:55:17"
```